# Photo not uploading on the web with reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am building a portfolio site with react js but the photo I am trying to use is not showing up on the web. I cant seem to find the errors so please help me figure out what I could be doing wrong

Here is the code where the image is contained

```
import Logo from '../../assets/fts_black.png'

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header>
      <div className="container header__container">
        <div className="me">
          <img src={Logo} alt="Logo" />
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header
```

This is the css code for the image

```
.me{
    background: var(--color-primary);
    width: 22rem;
    height: 30rem;
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 11rem);
    margin-top: 4rem;
    border-radius: 12rem 12rem 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5rem 1.5rem 1.5rem 1.5rem;
}
```

The styling is working just fine but the photo just doesnt want to show up. Please help

Comment: What is the project react version? Is it creat react app ? you need to make sure the proper png loader is supported in your app.

Comment: did that work in  your local env ?

Comment: Are you sure you uploaded the image to the server? Can you open it SEPARATELY in the browser?

Comment: The image path needs to be a relative path from the entry of the application.

Comment: @Afsanefda The react version I'm using is 18.1.0. Yes it is create react app. What could be the proper png loader? A previous png I used worked but on replacing it, the image doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Romylussone how do you mean? I dont quite understand

Comment: @ЮрийКопоть Yes I did and yes it opens separately in the browser

Comment: @JuhilSomaiya It is not in the entry application

Comment: @ChidimmaNworah, i want to know if the same code on your local test and then when you deploy it on the web online , it'doesn't work, that's your issue ?

Comment: It is still running on my localhost, not on the web yet

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your kind assistance, I realised I made a mistake in the root css in index.css by giving  the width of 1005 instead of 100%. I'm sorry for the inconvenience, bye

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that the path to the img location is correct? I am pretty new with React but the code seems fine.

Comment: Yes the path is alright. I am pretty sure of that because I just replaced the photo with this one that doesn't seem to show whereas the previous did. All I changed was the image name on the path. Also, the photo shows up on the internet